# How to find the longest existing substring of A's in a DNA string line and return the length?

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, dna-sequence

I came along the following problem and do not know how to solve it. The problem is to find the length of the longest substring of repeating A's and return the value of the length for every string in this list:

> ['>KF735813.1 HIV-1 isolate Cameroon1(ViroSeq) HIV DR 02 from Cameroon
>   pol protein (pol) gene, partial cds',
>   'CCTCAAATCACTCTTTGGCAACGACCCTTAGTCACAGTTAGGATAGAGGGACAGTTAATAGAAGCCCTATTAGACACAGG',
>   'GGCAGATGATACAGTATTAGAAGAGATAAATTTACCAGGAAAATGGAAACCAAAAATGATAGGGGGAATTGGAGGTTTTA',
>   'TCAAAGTAAGACAGTATGATCAGATACTTATAGAAATTTGTGGAAAAAGGGCCATAGGTACAGTATTAGTAGGACCTACA',
>   'CCTGTCAACATAATTGGACGAAACATGTTGACTCAGATTGGTTGTACTTTAAATTTTCCAATTAGTCCTATTGAAACTGT',
>   'GCCAGTAAAATTAAAGCCAGGTATGGATGGCCCAAAGGTAAAACAATGGCCATTGACAGAAGAAAAAATAAAAGCATTAA',
>   'CAGAAATTTGTACAGATATGGAAAAGGAGGGAAAAATTTCAATAATTGGGCCTGAAAATCCATATAATACTCCAGTATTT',
>   'GCCATAAAGAAAAAAGATAGTACTAAATGGAGAAAATTAGTAGATTTTAGAGAACTTAATAAGAGAACTCAAGACTTCTG',
>   'GGAGATCCAATTAGGAATACCTCATCCCGCGGGATTAAAAAAGAACAAATCAGTAACAGTACTAGATGTGGGGGATGCAT',
>   'ATTTTTCAGTTCCCTTAGATTAAGACTTTAGAAAGTACACTGCATTCACTATACCTAGTTTAAATAATGCAACACCAGGT',
>   'ATTAGATATCAGTACAATGTGCTTCCACAGGGATGGAAAGGATCACCAGCAATATTTCAGGCAAGCATGACAAAAATCTT',
>   'AGAGCCCTTTAGGACAAAATATCCAGAAATAGTGATCTACCAATATATGGATGATTTATATGTAGGATCAGACTTAGAGA',
>   'TAGGGCAGCATAGAGCAAAAATAGAGGAGTTGAGAGTACATCTATTGAAGTGGGGATTTACCACACCAGACAAAAAACAT',
>   'CAGAAAGAACCTCCATTTCTTTGGATGGGATATGAACTCCATCCTGACAAATGGACAGTCCAGCCTATACAGCTGCCAGA',
>   'AAAAGACAGCTGGACTGTCAATGATATACAGAAATTAGTGGGAAAACTAAATTGGGCAAGTCAGATTTATGCAGGAATTA',
>   'AAGTAAAGCAACTGTGTAGACTCCTCAGGGGAGCCAAAGCACTAACAGAGGTAGTACCACTAACTGAGGAAGCAGAATTA',
>   'GAATTGGCAGATAACAGGGAGATTCTAAAAGAACCTGTACATGGAGTATATTATGACCCAACAAAAGACTTAGTAGCAGA',
>   'AATACAGAAGCAAGGGCAAGAC']

Here is the function I have tried to do, but I know this is the wrong approach:

```
 for c in range(len(fastarec_Lines)):
        if fastarec_Lines[c].count('A') == current:
            count += 1
        else:
            count = 1
            current = fastarec_Lines[c]
    maximum = max(count,maximum)
    return maximum
```

Can someone help me out ?

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to do a regex find all search on the pattern `A+`.  Then, sort the resulting string based on length, and print out the last element:

```
seq = "AATTGGCCAAAAATTGCA"
matches = re.findall(r'A+', seq)
matches.sort(lambda x,y: cmp(len(x), len(y)))
print("longest string is " + matches[-1] + " with a length of " + str(len(matches[-1])))
```

This prints:

```
longest string is AAAAA with a length of 5
```